# Power supply/charger for Kobuki base

Tags: battery, hardware, turtlebot2, turtlebot, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a Kobuki base (Turtlebot 2) but my charger broke.

I am looking to replace the charger but I am unsure about the type of barrel connector used to connect to the Kobuki. I was only able to find the charger capacity specifications here: https://iclebo-kobuki.readthedocs.io/en/latest/anatomy.html

Does anyone know the exact type of barrel connector required?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/399704/power-supply/charger-for-kobuki-base/) by [optimisation](https://answers.ros.org/users/103243/optimisation/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2022-04-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The power supply that came with my Kobuki is the Delta Electronics ADP-65JH HB. The specifications on the label are:

Input:
100-240V, 1.5A, 50-60Hz

Output:
19VDC, 3.16A, 2.5mm ID x 5.5mm OD x 11.0mm Length, Positive Center Polarity

---

Originally posted by [LukeSchmitt](https://answers.ros.org/users/103655/lukeschmitt/) with karma: 16 on 2022-05-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [optimisation](https://answers.ros.org/users/103243/optimisation/) on 2022-05-16**:
Thank you very much for this data!